# Link decorations are affecting my fixed nav bar

Tags: html, css, containers, opacity, nav

I'm very new so please bear with me. My goal is to have my image links appear at half opacity and then at full opacity when hovering. This part is working but it is interfering with my fixed navbar at the top of my page.

If I scroll down until the image links are sort of "underneath" the navbar, the navbar becomes half opacity too. At this time, if I hover, they correctly show full opacity and appear to be "under" the navbar.

Here's my code:

```
.navbar{
  background-color: #50394c; 
  align-items: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
#container a:link{opacity:.5;}
#container a:hover{opacity:1;}
#container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding:20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

My HTML has this container ID with the div that contains all the links and images.

It doesn't seem to matter where I put the opacity setting(in the individual image element, the div class, as a link decoration, etc), it is still affecting the navbar once the element meets the navbar while scrolling.

Comment: Where is the image really in your code ?

Comment: my image is in my html:

<section id="projects">
    <div id="container"> 
      <a href="https://codepen.io/ChelseaS/full/vYGejgo">
        <img id="zappa" target="_blank"               
src="https://imgur.com/ciNLs8H.png" alt="Zappa Tribute Project" ></img></a>

Comment: No navbar is found in the link above : The link is to **Frank Zappa Tribute Page**

Comment: Could you set up an example on JSFidle or something similar? It will help others to understand and debug your problem.

Comment: yeah sorry, that was just part of my code.

https://codepen.io/ChelseaS/pen/YzqBWjx

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue, you want the navbar to not go underneath when you get down to the images. I'd recommend adding [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to the navbar so it's on top of the images. Adding code example

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #50394c;
  align-items: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* Add z-index */
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f4e1d2;
}

a:hover {
  color: #b2b2b2
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 10px 60px 0px 900px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.welcome {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  justify-content: sflex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 150px 150px 75px 50px;
}

.blurb {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #50394c;
}

#hello {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#protitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#container a:link {
  opacity: .5;
}

#container a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#zappa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #50394c;
}

#survey {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #50394c;
}

#techdoc {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #50394c;
}

#landing {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #50394c;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7.5rem;
  background-color: #50394c;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
}

.stripe-w {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.stripe-p {
  background-color: #50394c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

.contact-details {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  /*text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #1f1f1f;*/
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.nbutton {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  /*text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #1f1f1f;*/
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.contact-details:hover {
  transform: translateY(8px);
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.nbutton:hover {
  transform: translateY(8px);
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');
</style>
<main id="page-container">

  <navbar id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nbutton">
        <a href="#welcome-section">About</a></di>
      </li>
      <li class="nbutton">
        <a href="#projects">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nbutton">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </navbar>

  <section id="welcome-section" class="welcome">

    <div class="text" <h1 id="hello">
      Sample
      <br></h1>
      <p class="blurb">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper accumsan nunc eget consequat. Donec aliquet metus at urna venenatis, sed malesuada dui vehicula. Curabitur imperdiet risus ac viverra consequat. Nam rutrum volutpat tortor quis condimentum.
        Donec vel mi tincidunt, fermentum neque ac, pretium quam. Curabitur viverra placerat finibus. Cras massa felis, eleifend vitae malesuada id, bibendum a felis. Sed fringilla luctus tortor vel vulputate. Vivamus congue, ante in tristique pharetra,
        dolor massa interdum felis, a volutpat purus velit non sem. Nulla id tristique est, euismod varius ex. Donec scelerisque scelerisque massa sed consequat. Vestibulum dictum tortor mattis tristique commodo. Aliquam malesuada risus et sem consectetur,
        id malesuada elit dapibus. Nullam sagittis varius eros ut placerat.<br><br> Nunc gravida consectetur massa, sit amet laoreet tellus. Nulla ullamcorper tincidunt consequat. Quisque pulvinar aliquam turpis. Morbi tellus ex, consequat non
        venenatis vitae, commodo blandit dolor. Nulla congue velit nec dui fermentum pellentesque auctor in est. Nulla dui quam, vehicula quis vestibulum quis, rutrum nec ex. Nunc iaculis diam quis quam efficitur luctus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
        ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ante est, convallis ut accumsan ac, scelerisque quis erat. Morbi maximus quis erat eu finibus. Donec egestas et sapien ac pellentesque. Nulla quis aliquam libero. Ut dolor ligula, aliquam et nisi et, dapibus
        pharetra justo. Aenean ac libero id massa convallis vestibulum at non eros. In auctor diam neque, id pellentesque orci lobortis et.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div id="protitle" class="project"> Web Projects </div>

  <section id="projects">

    <div id="container">
      <a href="https://codepen.io/ChelseaS/full/vYGejgo">
        <img id="zappa" target="_blank" src="https://imgur.com/ciNLs8H.png" alt="Zappa Tribute Project"></img>
      </a>

      <a href="https://codepen.io/ChelseaS/full/bGpLqLb">
        <img id="techdoc" target="_blank" src="https://imgur.com/yEBeaXW.png" alt="Technical Document">
        </img>
      </a>

      <a href="https://codepen.io/ChelseaS/full/yLOPGJV">
        <img id="landing" target="_blank" src="https://imgur.com/OvBZLKD.png" alt="Product Landing Page"></img>
      </a>

      <a href="https://codepen.io/ChelseaS/pen/wvGPMMa">
        <img id="survey" target="_blank" src="https://imgur.com/6AIMSiT.png" alt="gaming survey">
        </img>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="stripe-w"></div>
  <footer id="contact" class="footer">

    <a id="profile-git" href="" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-github"></i> </a>

    <a id="profile-link" href="" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i> </a>

    <a id="profile-be" href="" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-behance"></i> </a>

    <a id="profile-mail" href="" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> </a>

  </footer>


</main>
```